# SSh-Agent Bash and Eval and Env

Tags: bash, ssh-agent

I have been reading about how ssh-agent works and how it relates to the shell environment. I understand why we do eval `ssh-agent` now (usually in /etc/profile), it makes logical sense. However the output of ssh-agent seems a little unnatural to me

```
# The bad way just (env dont get set, just printed) so i can see its output
[matt@laparchie rc.d]$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-EQUsXLxh4103/agent.4103; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=4104; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 4104;
```

Why doesnt ssh-agent just output

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-EQUsXLxh4103/agent.4103;
export SSH_AGENT_PID=4104;
echo Agent pid 4104;
```

When pumped to eval both do the same (i.e. setting env variables), but the latter is less verbose and more clear to me, is it just a style (the verbosity of the first)? and if so does the style have a history/reason? or is there something technically different?

Comment: BASH is not the only shell.  People using other shells want to use SSH too.

Answer (score 2):

What ssh-agent outputs is `sh` syntax.  The `export varname=value` construct is valid in `bash` but is not recognized by many implementations of `sh` whereas the `varname=value; export varname` construct is.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, `X=Y; export X` is the right way.

But because it's unnecessary verbose, `bash` (as well as `sh` and `zsh`) provides shortcut `export X=Y`, which does exactly the same.

Actually, I don't know any shell, which uses `export X` to set environment variables, but does not understand `export X=Y`, but still using more verbose way is considered more portable.